# OAuth2 authentication for appengine stopped working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I have a periodic job that pulls data from my appengine datastore using remote api.
This job suddenly stopped working because google decided not to like my server anymore.
It works on my machine, though.

Here's what happens in a python shell on my machine:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
>>> app = 'qmagicobr2.appspot.com'
>>> remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(app, '/_ah/remote_api')
<google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOAuth2 object at 0x7f5cdfac61d0>
>>>
```

And here's what happens with the same code on my server

```
(qmbi)dashboard@ip-172-31-32-222:~/qmbi$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
>>> app = 'qmagicobr2.appspot.com'
>>> remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(app, '/_ah/remote_api')
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.apis+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=None&access_type=offline

Enter verification code:
```

When I go to the URL above I get an error page that says:

> 401. That’s an error.
>        Error: invalid_client
>        The OAuth client was not found.
>        Request Details
>        access_type=offline
>        scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.apis https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
>        response_type=code
>        redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
>        client_id=None
>        That’s all we know.

Help?

**---- UPDATE (2016-05-12) -----**

I forgot to mention the authentication file I'm using.
For `ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth` to work I need to have an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to a credentials file.
I do.
In both environments (my machine, and the server) `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` points to a json file (the same file in both environments) with the following format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "qmagicobr2",
  "private_key_id": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....AAAA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "dashboard@qmagicobr2.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "0000000000000000000000",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/dashboard%40qmagicobr2.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

This file was generated using Appengine's developer console, under "Credentials / Service Account Keys / Manage Service accounts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just tested this particular use case and the fact that client id is `none` reveals a lot.

`ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth` accepts using a service account with a key file, providing oauth2 params as an `appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOAuth2.OAuth2Parameters` object where you can specify the `client id`, `secret`, `scope` etc. [OAuth2Parameters Doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc_httplib2#google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOAuth2.OAuth2Parameters)

But the easiest way to mitigate the situation though is to use the [gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) to properly authenticate your server:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the authentication file I'm using, I'm updating the question.

Comment: I added more information about the authentication file, can you please take a look on my update?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for your answer! I installed gcloud on the server and went through the authentication process (pasting the link on the browser and the code back into the terminal). That worked. I noticed it created `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`. I pointed my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to that file, and it worked!